# Powermock/Easymock tests take 10x as long when not on VPN

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, easymock

I'll be as specific as I can with this...

Basically, the current unit tests for a large java project take around 19m30s to run when not on an OpenVPN network. When on the OpenVPN network, the tests take about 2m0s to run. Why is this?

From what I can tell, there are no external calls being made. One specific test takes 1m36s off VPN and then 1s when on VPN. Are the tests written inefficiently? Where should I start looking to improve the time it takes off the VPN? What could cause issues like this?

We are using Powermock and Easymock to do the unit tests. The specific test above uses an in-memory database.

Comment: You don't run tests "on a network". Where are the tests being run? What do you mean by "on" or "not on" the network? (And have you profiled the tests to see which ones are slow?)

Comment: are there host names involved that only resolve when connected to the OpenVPN?

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer how would I find this out? what I mean is that I'm running the tests through maven on IntelliJ on my local machine without being connected to a VPN for work and the tests run slow. When I connect to the VPN and run the tests in IntelliJ, the tests run much faster.

Comment: it looks like you might be running into timeout issues, i.e. some services are not available when not connected to the VPN. Often these are DNS problems. I would start with any config file that the tests are using which might be host names and check those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyones help. It turns out that theres a bug with Mac OS X that caused the tests to initialize much slower than on linux. When I went to do integration testing with timeouts on the connection services, everything worked much faster.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that no network calls are made. For example, if you use SOAP services the wsdl file could be retrieved implicitly. Use wireshark, fiddler or other software for network analysis.

Secondly, run JVM profiling and see where the most of the time being spent. Having this huge difference (1 minute vs 1 second)   should be easy to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the mocking frameworks. However the test content can cause such thing. In general it is caused by code trying to do DNS resolution, even for localhost (`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`).

Your best bet is to do a bunch of thread dumps during the test and look for network code like above.

The solution is usually to add a line in `/etc/hosts` to resolve quickly what your test is looking for. Or to fix the network but sometimes it's not that easy.